# Lost ability to navigate to WordPress site via URL or IP

Tags: wordpress

Yesterday I tried to change the URL to my WordPress blog through the options panel on the website itself.  This broke the website and I couldn't log in any more.  Luckily I have access and all the permissions to SSH into the server where everything is hosted and served from.

So I tried all the suggestions from the [WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) article about changing your URL and nothing has worked.  I've tried editing the `functions.php` for the theme as well as the root `wp-config.php` as suggested and neither worked.  I also tried updating the `wp_options` entries in the database, but this still hasn't worked.  I can't even get a response from the server by browsing to the IP address (both private and elastic) but neither works.  I've made sure that the mysqld and httpd services are running, but I'm still not getting a response.

Is there another record where the pertinent information is being kept that I don't know about?

Comment: Try removing your htaccess file as well. Does the website try to redirect when you navigate to the new URL?

Comment: It slowly attempts to serve the webpage, but eventually fails

Comment: You need to change 2 values in the `wp_options` table. `siteurl` and `home`. Once you've done that, be sure to log in to the admin panel and go to `settings>permalinks` and click `save` to update your permalink structure.

Comment: Is there a server-side alternative to the admin panel? I can't access it currently through a browser.